# ACF Repeater field Display

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have created a custom post type called 'products' and a custom taxonomy within the post type called 'Ingredients'.

I've added a repeater field called 'ingredients-INCI' and sub field of 'ingredients-INCI-group' which calls the values from the taxonomy 'Ingredients'.

Custom Repeater Field Screenshot:

[image: Click to view Custom Repeater Field Screenshot]

Each product has many ingredients, I would like to display a list of the chosen ingredients for the product. Here's my template code:

```html
<?php
/**
PostType Page Template: Product
 */

get_header(); ?>

 <div id="b_primary" class="b_content-area">
  <main id="b_main" class="b_site__main" role="main">

  <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

<!-- START product information -->
            
            <div class="toptext">If you have any enquiries, please click here to contact us.</div>
            <div class="toptext">Please ensure you include all the products information that you wish to enquire about.</div>
            <div class="tableproduct">
            <table>
  <tr>
      <th><div class="tabletitle">PRODUCT NAME</div></th>
    <th><div class="tableresult"><?php wp_title(); ?></div></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><div class="tabletitle">PRODUCT DESCRIPTION</div></td>
    <td><div class="tableresult"><?php the_field('product_description'); ?></div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><div class="tabletitle">BRAND</div></td>
    <td><div class="tableresult"><?php the_field('brand'); ?></div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><div class="tabletitle">BARCODE</div></td>
    <td><div class="tableresult"><?php the_field('barcode'); ?></div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><div class="tabletitle">Ingredients (INCI Name)<br><div class="tablesubtitle">NOTE: Ingredients are listed in decreasing order of quantity.</div></div></td>
    <td><div class="tableresult">

  <?php

// check if the repeater field has rows of data
if( have_rows('ingredients-INCI') ):

  // loop through the rows of data
    while ( have_rows('ingredients-INCI') ) : the_row();

        // display a sub field value
        the_sub_field('ingredients-INCI-group');

    endwhile;

else :

    // no rows found

endif;

?>

        </div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><div class="tabletitle">Fragrance Ingredients (INCI Name)<br><div class="tablesubtitle">NOTE: Fragrance Ingredients are those which require listing under EC648/2004 on detergents.</div></div></td>
    <td><div class="tableresult">
  
  RESULTS HERE
  
</div></td>
  </tr>
</table>
                <div class="tabletitleother">OTHER INFORMATION</div>
                <div class="tableotherresults">The above formulation is for products manufactured between <?php the_field('date_from'); ?> and <?php the_field('date_to'); ?></div>
                <div class="tableyellow">INCI / CAS / Ingredient information CLICK HERE or HERE</div>
            </div>
            
<!-- END product information -->

  <?php endwhile; // End of the loop. ?>

  </main><!-- #b_main -->
 </div><!-- #b_primary -->

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

This code seems to break the output. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
$productField = get_field('ingredients-INCI');
```

All the repeater fileds will be listed in this "$productField" valriable.

```
foreach($productField as $product){
   echo $product['ingredients-INCI-group'];
}
```

Comment: You have to display your content in loop.  "$productField" in this variable you will get all the values of "ingredients-INCI" this field. I have updated my answer please check

Comment: I tried your suggestion but not having much luck. I should have added in my first post that 'ingredients-INCI-group' is pulled through from a custom taxonomy called 'ingredients'. If I turn that subfield into a standard text field it pulls though the content however when I turn it back to pull though from the custom taxonomy it doesnt.

Comment: Please print this variable. Are you getting all the values. <?php print_r($productField) ?>

Comment: So do I add the following   <?php $productField = get_field('ingredients-INCI');

foreach($productField as $product){
   echo $product['ingredients-INCI-group'];
} ?>
  <?php print_r($productField) ?>

Comment: You need to add only this.  <?php $productField = get_field('ingredients-INCI'); foreach($productField as $product){ echo $product['ingredients-INCI-group']; } ?>. Be sure this (ingredients-INCI) should be your field name as in the screenshot.

Comment: I'm really sorry but this does not work! Nothing comes up, also the rest of the page below where this code is inserted does not load.

Comment: This is my code:  <tr>
    <td><div class="tabletitle">Ingredients (INCI Name)<br><div class="tablesubtitle">NOTE: Ingredients are listed in decreasing order of quantity.</div></div></td>
    <td><div class="tableresult">
  
  <?php $productField = get_field('ingredients-INCI'); foreach($productField as $product){ echo $product['ingredients-INCI-group']; } ?>
  
        </div></td>
  </tr>